# dhcpsapi.exe File keep running in task manager

Tags: windows, virus-scanning

I have a file with description "Подключаемый модуль пересылки событий WS-Management" and name dhcpsapi.exe running in task manager. It seems like a virus to me.Whenever i tried to delete or open its location i am getting access denied in my admin account.Tried to delete it from cmd-Administrator but keep getting the error 'Access Denied'.

I can't see its folder in file explorer or in hidden files but can see it in command prompt (dir /a).
I need to access this folder and delete it. How do i access it from command prompt or from windows explorer.
[Screenshot of file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHsG4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I unchecked hide protected items from folder options. Then gave permission to User but it was still inaccessible and windows defender scanned that folder and identified it as a trojan virus and removed the process from task manager. Then i deleted that folder with a software 'unlocker' from drive and recycle bin.

[Screenshot of file details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUHxs.png)